# Subgroup of elements of finite order

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ the subset of elements with finite order. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Here is my attempt at a proof.

> We need to check closure and the existence of an identity and inverses. Associativity is inherited from $G$.
>
> Let $a,b \in H$. Then $a$ and $b$ have finite orders $n$ and $m$, respectively. We first check that $ab \in H$. As $G$ is abelian, we have
> \begin{align*}
> (ab)^{mn} & = a^{mn} b^{mn} \\
> & = (a^n)^m (b^m)^n \\
> & = e^m e^n \\
> & = ee \\
> & = e.  
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, the order of $ab$ divides $mn$. In particular, $ab$ has finite order, so $ab \in H$. Second, we have $e \in H$, as $e$ has finite order $1$. Finally, we show that since $a \in H$, $a^{-1} \in H$. We have
> \begin{align*}
> (a^{-1})^m & = (a^m)^{-1} \\
> & = e^{-1} \\
> & = e.
> \end{align*}
> In particular, if $a^k = e$ if and only if $(a^{-1})^k = e$, so $|a| = |a^{-1}|$, so $a^{-1}$ has finite order and is therefore an element of $H$.

How does this proof look? There are some moments where I feel I was insufficiently precise. For example, I did not commend on the order of $ab$. I believe its order is not $mn$, but $\text{lcm}(m,n)$, but I am not 100% sure on this.

Comment: Your proof looks fine. There's no need to determine the exact order of $ab$ to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: The problem as stated is incorrect; you need the hypothesis that $G$ is abelian (which you say in the proof but not in the problem statement).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: that edit is pending : )

Comment: Side note: the order of $ab$ can be any intermediate divisor between lcm$(m,n)/\gcd(m,n)$ and lcm$(m,n)$. (Consider the case $a=b^{-1}$ for example to confirm that lcm$(m,n)$ isn't always correct.)

Comment: Please note that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/716176/104041) is not a duplicate, since the question here is a [tag:solution-verification] post.

Comment: Please compare with the standard solutions given at this post, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716176/abstract-algebra-let-mathitg-be-an-abelian-group-show-that-the-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1) to verify your own solution. This is also helpful.